# How do I specify a plan file when doing terraform plan output to show the contents of a plan file?

Tags: terraform

My plan file saved under a specific name. I've tried
`terraform plan planfilename.plan -out=tfplan`
and a show other variations that include the plan file name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save a plan to a location you can use:

```
terraform plan --out=<filename>
```

To inspect this plan, you can use the `show` command:

```
terraform show <filename>
```

To apply this plan, you can do the following:

```
terraform apply <filename>
```

Comment: It would be good to also mention the file reason `show` is necessary here is because the file is binary encoded, and therefore needs to be decoded into useful output.

Answer (score 3):

```
terraform plan -out=tfplan
```

the flag "-out" is to specify the output filename. So in this case, your output file is "tfplan". If you want to specify multiple output files, for whatever reason, you could do something weird like:

```
terraform plan -out=tfplan; cat tfplan > planefilename.plan
```

Comment: I would suggest changing the `;` to `&&`, otherwise, that command will create an empty file if terraform is broken for some reason.